# Jenkins pipeline build history.

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have configured the Jenkins pipeline and its working fine but it does not show the size of the builds on the dashboards in the build history.I have the disk usage plugin installed as well. I see that on a normal Jenkins job its showing there but in the pipeline it does not show the Size. Please help me w/  this  [Build historyImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0s8Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

CloudBees Simple Disk Usage Plugin won't work on Windows masters. try Disk Usage Plugin.

Comment: I am using the Disk Usage Plug and Its on a Linux host .  but it does not reflect the build history Size. Though Its working on the normal Jobs.

Comment: ensure that Jenkins process started in elevated mode

Comment: There is a bug [https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40643] in the DiskUsage Plugin.